# How do I create a trigger in MySQL that will automatically create a new record and assigns a default value for that new record?

Tags: mysql, database, text, syntax, command

Let's say I already have some tables, namely: Doctors, Patients, Prescription, Sickness & Medicine Table to start off with and I was given the question below to write  texts before executing the commands.

Here's the question:

Question: Write SQL statements to create the following triggers on a notepad and save it as triggers.txt

Task:

-When a new patient is registered a trigger fires to automatically create a new record in the prescription table and assign a default doctor (in order to achieve this there must be a default doctor inserted in the doctors table first) to treat that patient.

-When a new sickness is added a trigger should run to create a new treatment for it with default values being added for medicine (in order for this to work there must be at least one default medicine record inserted first into the medicine table).

---

The problem is I actually don't know how to create a trigger and also to create default values.

Please help, I just need to write it and save it as a text document.

I haven't tried anything because I do not know what trigger is but I am expecting to write it on a notepad and save it as triggers.txt according to the question.

Comment: *The problem is I actually don't know to create a trigger* [CREATE TRIGGER Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-trigger.html) *and also to create default values.* This is common value which can be either specified in the table structure or hardcoded in the trigger (hardcoded value will override column default value).

Comment: @Akina _Thank you for the correction. Can you please make an example for my problem? Those two paragraphs under the "Question" is the task I am required to do. Thank you.

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)